Why is the name "Ram" not present in Vishnu Sahasranama? (mahabharat version)
There is Krishna in the list of names, but I dont see Ram.
I am wondering if anyone knows why.
Not counting the

SriRam, Ram, Rameti .....

verse because that is not part of the 108 vishnu naam slokas.
Not counting other names defining Ram, like

Kapindra

Looking for the literal name "Ram", which is arguably the most powerful name in Kaliyug, why is it not part of the original 108 names?

Shri Raama (Rama/Ram) name is indeed present in Shri Vishnu Sahasranamam (Mahabharata version) as 394th name:


raamo viraamo virajo maargo neyo nayo-anayah
veerah saktimataam-sreshthah dharmo dharmaviduttamah.


oh yes right! thanks I totally missed it.
